# Grub points to recovery partition instead of install partition

Tags: grub2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dual Boot issues with Windows 7 and Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40149/dual-boot-issues-with-windows-7-and-ubuntu)

I just setup a dual boot system but there is a slight problem. The Win7 grub entry points to the recovery partition instead of the partition where the install resides.

It currently points to `/dev/sda3/` instead of `/dev/sda4/`. Moreover I tried to edit the boot parameters in grub but I think there is more to it. I am not sure if MBR needs some fix too because I get a BSOD just after I boot, even after I changed it to /dev/sda4/ but there was some entry like hd0 too, so that could be wrong.

How to go about changing the grub entry?

[image]

Comment: If windows does not boot, can you determine the error message ?

Comment: @bodhi.zaren I tried the fix in your link, and I ended up with Bootmgr missing error but I am not sure I have done what I am trying to do right now. About windows error, its nothng specific. Too generic like scan for virus, check disk `fsck` etc

Comment: Google search 'Bootmgr missing'

Comment: Have been trying all sorts of solutions I can find, for once I even overwrote my grub but then recovered it back.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,