# Windows 7 won't boot after installing Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I'm having a pretty serious problem right now that I hope someone can help me with. I can't seem to load Windows 7. I just started and set up a dual boot of Windows 7 and Ubuntu. My windows was working fine before installing Ubuntu. However now whenever I select the Windows loader option in the Grub menu it won't work. It will appear like its starting to load but then after a few minutes it will take me to the startup repair screen (I think that's what its called). After several minutes of waiting it says that it can't repair it and suggests using the system repair disc...which I don't have.

I've have searched and tried several different "solutions" to no success. Is there a way I can create a System Repair disc using a USB drive from Ubuntu?? Doesn't seem possible to me.

Or could it be that Grub isn't loading Windows 7 correctly? Is there anyway I can just bypass Grub? Or not use it at all. Maybe what I'm trying to ask is can I boot Windows 7 directly from the BIOS menu or something?

I wish I never had even considered dual booting and should have just stuck to a virtual machine.

Can anyone help??

Comment: Can you take a photo of the `grub` screen and upload it somewhere? Sometimes you have several `windows` entries, and sometimes the other entry works fine.

Comment: Here is a link of the grub screen: http://imgur.com/DDHJIQM

Comment: I think I've figured out what is happening. Grub is only showing the Recovery partition of Windows. The partition with windows on it should be on /dev/sdb1. Any idea how to change that?

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary solution, you can always select the `Windows` entry, hit <kbd>e</kbd>, then find `/dev/sdb1` and change it to `/dev/sdb2`. If you want the modification to become permanent, look for example at [How do I change the GRUB boot order?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order) or, better, at [Grub points to recovery partition instead of install partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88830/grub-points-to-recovery-partition-instead-of-install-partition).

Comment: I tried the editing the /dev/sdb2 to /dev/sdb1 and booting but it didn't solve anything. I also looked at the links you posted. I learned that in gparted the windows 7 partition is listed as unknown and it isn't listed when I use the sudo blkid command in terminal

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/v2USsdo.jpg  This is an image of my GParted screen. The Windows 7 install partition is the first one but it is listed as unknown. Shouldn't it be ntfs or something?

Comment: Here is an image of the terminal screen when the fdisk -l and blkid commands are ran. The Win7 partition is listed in fdisk -l but not in the blkid list... http://i.imgur.com/KcqANOt.jpg

Comment: I am not sure what exactly is going wrong. Please consider updating the original question with some of the relevant info that you're putting in comments (including the screenshots which are relevant); this will increase your chances of getting a useful answer. And do search AskUbuntu for similar issues in the `[grub2][dual-boot]` tags, as there seems to be a mountain of similar questions.